# Change column ordering and resize

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Currently I have column for desktop that looks like this:

```
[ A ] [ B ]
```

But now I need to change it when viewed in mobile in this order and size

```
[ B ]
[ A ]
```

How can I achieve it with Boostrap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap's [push and pull](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) classes.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6">Column B</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">Column A</div>
  </div>
</div>
```